# Is there a way to CSS animate text movement after new text elements are added

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to animate the movement of text when more text is shown in the same line through style.display (and to fade in the new text), How do I achieve this with CSS animation?

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("secondary")[0].style.display = "none";

function show() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("secondary")[0].style.display = "";
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <a class="primary" id="about" onclick="show();">text 1 </a>
  <a class="secondary" id="email">more text</a>
</div>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Ycmelon/g1bdvmpx/

expected result: https://s3.gifyu.com/images/3dr3h5.gif)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start by setting the width of `.wrapper` to the width of `.primary`. This will hide the "more text". When clicked restore the width of `.wrapper` to the original width, and changes the opacity of the `.secondary`.

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
const primary = document.querySelector('.primary');
const secondary = document.querySelector('.secondary');

const wrapperWidth = wrapper.getBoundingClientRect().width + 'px';
const primaryWidth = primary.getBoundingClientRect().width + 'px';

wrapper.style.width = primaryWidth;

wrapper.classList.add('ready'); // apply the transition to wrapper after the setting the base width

wrapper.addEventListener('click', () => {
  wrapper.style.width = wrapperWidth;
  secondary.style.opacity = 1;
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ready {
  transition: width 1s;
}

.secondary {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a class="primary" id="about">text 1</a>
    <a class="secondary" id="email">more text</a>
  </div>
  
  <br>
  
  <div style="text-align: center">text 1</div> <!-- before -->
  <div style="text-align: center">text 1 more text</div> <!-- after -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! However, the original text is not perfectly centered before clicking (then both texts together are). Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: I've updated the code, so everything would be centered.

Comment: With the updated code, both texts together are not centered? Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Now it should be centered in both states.